Unrecognized base64 character
I am getting the
logs (2737691557)|FATAL_ERROR|System.StringException: Unrecognized base64 character: { (System Code) Class.docusignGenAndSendAPI.gen_and_convert: line 68, column 1  (2737703234)|FATAL_ERROR|System.StringException: Unrecognized base64 character:
Please could someone advise what I am doing wrong in the code?


    @future(callout = true)  
    public static void gen_and_convert(Id recordId){
       
        String jsonBody = bodyJSON(recordId);  
        System.debug(jsonBody); 
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('callout:{namedCredential/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/generate_and_convert');

        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody(jsonBody); 
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        String base64Content = (String) JSON.deserialize( response.getBody(), String.class ); 
        System.debug(base64Content);
        //the below line is causing the error I think
        Blob blobContent = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Content);


In trying to shorten the error, you've left out the most important parts of it. Please [edit] your question so that it contains the entirety of the error message, verbatim (including the stack trace). Also, please call out the specific line that the error is occurring on in a separate code block (so that we don't need to manually count out 50+ lines of code to figure out where the issue is).

Also, using JSONGenerator is almost always a mistake. It'll work, but it's a lot more verbose and prone to errors than creating a Map<String, Object> and using JSON.serialize().

Again, please [edit] your post to add that information.

I don't know where line 68 is in your code, but there is some conversion going on, assuming a base64 encoded string. And this string turns out to contain a "{" - according to your comment 40 mins ago (but you seem to have dropped this important part in the edit of your post). This character is not base64.

The important clue here is

Unrecognized base64 character: {

You're getting a JSON response from the DocuSign api, not a Base64 one.
It's not clear what that JSON looks like because I can't find the resource you're trying to use in DocuSign's own documentation on the envelopes resource.
The JSON may contain some base64 data, but it is not itself base64. You need to properly deserialize the JSON you're getting (trying to deserialize it as a string is not appropriate) to get at the data inside of it.
Again, because there isn't any documentation I can find, I can't give you a specific solution. Finding the proper documentation for that "generate_and_convert" resource is going to be the key here. That should give you an idea of the structure of the JSON response, which you can then create Apex classes for to aid in the deserialization (or just use JSON.deserializeUntyped(), but be prepared for a lot of manual typecasting if you go that route).
Reading through How do I get started working with JSON in Apex, one of our canonical-qa tagged questions, will get you more prepared for the Apex part of this if you're not familiar with handling JSON.
